# Map polygons and markers disappear using leaflet

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, leaflet

For some reason my polygons are not showing once the map tiles are rendered. They are drawn on the map but disappear once the map tiles are rendered.

I have created a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ihatemash/nr7pjbp0/5/) example of the issue. The polygon should be in the center of the map and your mouse pointer will change whenever you hover over the polygon area. Sometimes I see the red polygon display for a second just before the tiles are rendered. So, I know it is getting drawn on the map. This happens with my map pins as well. But, I didn't include a map pin in the JSFiddle example.

```js
var tdata = '{"Latitude":79.07181,"Longitude":-100.63477,"Polygons":[[{"Item1":79,"Item2":-100},{"Item1":79,"Item2":-99},{"Item1":78.5,"Item2":-99},{"Item1":78.5,"Item2":-100}]]}';

dta = JSON.parse(tdata);

var map = new L.Map('map', { center: new L.LatLng(dta.Latitude, dta.Longitude), zoom: 6, maxZoom: 16, minZoom: 5 });
var osm = new L.TileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png');
var ggl = new L.Google();
var ggl2 = new L.Google('TERRAIN');
map.addLayer(ggl2);
map.addControl(new L.Control.Layers({ 'Street': osm }, {}));

for (var x = 0; x < dta.Polygons.length; x++) {
    var polygon = dta.Polygons[x];
    var coordinates = [[]];
    coordinates.pop();
    for (var j = 0; j < polygon.length; j++) {
        var point = polygon[j];
        coordinates.push(new Array(point.Item1, point.Item2));
    }

    var mapPolygon = L.polygon(coordinates,{fillColor: "#FF0000", fillOpacity: dta.Opacity, weight: '1px'});
    mapPolygon.addTo(map);
}
```

Comment: I don't see anything with that in either IE or Chrome.

Comment: So you see the map marker and the red polygon? Neither of them display in IE, Chrome, or Firefox for me.

Comment: Not sure why this post got down voted and a vote to close but it's not working for my co-worker either. If you see the marker and polygon, please let me know.

Comment: I don't see anything at all with the posted code, but I don't know much about leaflet..

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm using leaflet to draw zip code boundaries and map pins on the map. This is just a simple polygon example to show the issue I'm having. The map should show a big read box on the map along with a map pin. I can see them for a split second when the page loads (keep refreshing and you may see them) but then they disappear when the map tiles are rendered.

Comment: Perhaps you can create a proper [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and post it on [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/) or JSFiddle so that people can easily produce your problem? At the moment it's a one paragraph question and 110 lines of code of which half is irrelevant. Maybe that's why you got downvoted. If interested read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/44598/leaflet-google-map-baselayer-markers-not-visible

Comment: I created a jsFiddle example but the polygon & map pin show. So, I created a simple html example of the problem.  This is close to the same code I'm using in production with a lot of things removed to simplify it as much as possible. I guess I could have removed more but I wanted someone to be able to copy the code into a page and see the issue instead of using code snippets since I can't recreate the issue in jsFiddle. The code to generate the polygon and map pin work. they just disappear once the map tiles are rendered. I'll try to simplify the example further. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 2):

The [`weight` option](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.0.html#path-weight) must be a number, not a string containing CSS units.

Answer (score 0):

It occurs since rectangle is rendered on map pane but Goggle layer is displayed on top of map pane.

One solution would be to change order of map pane and Google layer by setting z-index via CSS:

```
.leaflet-map-pane {
    z-index: 2 !important;
}

.leaflet-google-layer {
    z-index: 1 !important;
}
```

**Example**

```js
$(function () {

    var tdata = '{"Latitude":79.07181,"Longitude":-100.63477,"Polygons":[[{"Item1":79,"Item2":-100},{"Item1":79,"Item2":-99},{"Item1":78.5,"Item2":-99},{"Item1":78.5,"Item2":-100}]]}';

    var dta = JSON.parse(tdata);

    var map = new L.Map('map', { center: new L.LatLng(dta.Latitude, dta.Longitude), zoom: 6, maxZoom: 16, minZoom: 5 });
    var osm = new L.TileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png');
    var ggl = new L.Google('TERRAIN');
    var layer = map.addLayer(ggl);
    map.addControl(new L.Control.Layers({ 'Street': osm }, {}));

    for (var x = 0; x < dta.Polygons.length; x++) {
        var polygon = dta.Polygons[x];
        var coordinates = [[]];
        coordinates.pop();
        for (var j = 0; j < polygon.length; j++) {
            var point = polygon[j];
            coordinates.push(new Array(point.Item1, point.Item2));
        }

        var mapPolygon = L.polygon(coordinates, { fillColor: "#FF0000", fillOpacity: dta.Opacity, weight: 1 });
        mapPolygon.addTo(map);
    }

});
```

```css
#map { 
    height: 600px; 
}



.leaflet-map-pane {
    z-index: 2 !important;
}

.leaflet-google-layer {
    z-index: 1 !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet/v0.7.7/leaflet.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet/v0.7.7/leaflet.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://matchingnotes.com/javascripts/leaflet-google.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```

[Modified JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vgrem/nr7pjbp0/16/)